# Google Contact Synchronization on the iPhone 3G

Tags: gmail, iphone, gmail-contacts

I don't have my contacts stored in my Google account, but I'd like them to be in my gmail account.  I figured if I set up Google Sync (basically GMail as an Exchange server) that my contacts would find their way up to GMail.  Unfortunately the push only seems from GMail to iPhone.

What do I have to do to push my contacts up to GMail? Is there some other utility that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is that you had pre-existing contacts on the iPhone which you want to import into Gmail....

I don't believe there is a way to do this. You will have to use [one of the import methods](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=14024) to get the contacts on Gmail initially.

Once that is set up, you will be able to create or edit contacts on your iPhone and they will be synced to Gmail.

Comment: That's pretty much it.  Had to hook the phone up to iTunes then use iTunes to push the contacts. For reference, new contacts did push both ways just fine, I guess I expected an initial push into GMail of all my iPhone contacts, but no joy.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it might be an issue with your setup. I have Google Sync enabled with my iPhone 3G and i can push data both ways. There is a thread [here](http://www.google.la/support/forum/p/Google+Mobile/thread?tid=79895cb61ff6d728&hl=en) about a similar issue happening with other people.

Answer (score 0):

I use a service called MemoToo and you can [check out how I set it up on my blog](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/archive/2010/07/07/the-search-for-a-single-point-of-truth.aspx). Although I don't have an iPhone, MemoToo suports it and there are a number of SyncML enabled application you can get for your iPhone.

If you go to http://memotoo.com and setup an account you can have your contacts synced with tons of services including:

- Outlook
- Google Contacts
- Google Calander
- Facebook (One way)
- LinkedIn (One way)
- Windows Live Contacts
- Yahoo Contacts
- Twitter
- Windows Mobile
- Android
- Plaxo
- Soocial
- SheduleWorld
- UNYK
- Vodafone 360 (this is a realy crap service though)
- And tones more

Its also ver cheap and you only need to pay £12 per year if you have more than 50 contacts. I have 2000+ and it work just fine.

I did have a couple of hours of De-duping to do afterwords with so many services, but once you have sone that once all is good. Most dups can be deleted, but if you have a contact on Facebook and LinkedIn it is better to merge them.

The problem I have with just using Gmail is that "I" have to keep my contacts up to date. Using this I can have accounts on LiinkedIn, Plaxo and all the other services that my contacts use and have all that data merges into a single point of truth. I even use UNYK even though I only have 13 contacts on there. This method lets all of your contacts use whatever service they like to update their contacts and all those updates flow into your address book. Its magic!